# How to insert notification feature by using Cordova Plugin?

Tags: cordova

I have problem with inserting notification with cordova local notification plugin. After I have installed notification plugin, this is the code I wrote to my js sheet.

```
alert("Hey you!");
    try { cordova.plugins.notification.local.launchDetails } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message)};
```

and I got the error as shown in the second picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynrQ5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw2Bu.png)

Anyone know how to resolve the error? Or if you know the complete step-by-step method on how to insert notification feature, would you mind sharing? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'phonegap' instead of 'cordova'? It helped me fix a lot of issues before:

So instead of using:

```
try { cordova.plugins.notification.local.launchDetails } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message)};
```

Try using:

```
try { phonegap.plugins.notification.local.launchDetails } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message)};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Unfortunately, it says "phonegap is not defined"

Comment: Are you executing your code on app startup or in a later stage? It might be a possibility that cordova has not loaded yet.

Comment: I executed my code on the beginning of my js sheet, this should be the startup stage right?